# C# Using Class in LinkedList

Tags: c#, class, oop, linked-list, nodes

I have been trying to add a class into my `LinkedList`, but I kept getting `0` when I display all. Either that or I get an error saying I cannot convert the `class` to `int`. Please help me out.

I'm trying to make a program whereby I can enter books into the `LinkedList`, and then make the list display all. I will be showing 3 files "Program.cs", "LinkedList.cs" and "Node.cs", I will leave my "Item.cs" out as I don't think it's the one causing the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookApp
{
    class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList Books = new LinkedList();
            Item book1 = new Item(101, "Avatar: Legend of Korra", 13.50);
            Item book2 = new Item(102, "Avatar: Legend of Aang", 10.60);
            Books.AddFront(book1);
            Books.AddFront(book2);

            Books.DisplayAll();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my LinkedList.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using BookApp;

class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;  // 1st node in the linked list
    private int count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = value; }
    }

    public Node Head
    {
        get { return head; }
    }
    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;    // creates an empty linked list
        count = 0;
    }

    public void AddFront(Item z)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(z);
        newNode.Link = head;
        head = newNode;
        count++;

    }

    public void DeleteFront()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            head = head.Link;
            count--;
        }
    }

    public void DisplayAll()
    {
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.Data);
            current = current.Link;
        }
    }

}
```

and lastly here's my node.cs

```
class Node
{
    private int data;

    public int Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
    private Node link;
    private BookApp.Item p;

    internal Node Link
    {
        get { return link; }
        set { link = value; }
    }

    public Node(BookApp.Item p)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.data = p; //Where I got my error about how I cannot convert type BookApp.Item to int
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect of us? Place breakpoints, start debugging, inspect your variables.

Comment: You *do* know that .NET comes with a pre-built [`LinkedList<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `node.cs` try replacing :

```
private int data;
public int Data
{
    get { return data; }
    set { data = value; }
}
```

By:

```
private BookApp.Item data;
public BookApp.Item Data
{
    get { return data; }
    set { data = value; }
}
```

You can't assign an `Item` to an `integer`, that's why you facing this error.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but if you're looking to create your own implementation of a linked list, can I suggest you use generics to allow you to use your code with ANY data type?

If you modified your LinkedList to make it a LinkedList< T >:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class LinkedList<T>
{
    private Node<T> head;  // 1st node in the linked list
    private int count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = value; }
    }

    public Node<T> Head
    {
        get { return head; }
    }
    public LinkedList<T>()
    {
        head = null;    // creates an empty linked list
        count = 0;
    }

    public void AddFront(T z)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(z);
        newNode.Link = head;
        head = newNode;
        count++;

    }

    public void DeleteFront()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            head = head.Link;
            count--;
        }
    }

    public void DisplayAll()
    {
        Node<T> current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.Data);
            current = current.Link;
        }
    }

}
```

And your Node to a Node< T >:

```
class Node<T>
{
    private T data;

    public T Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
    private Node<T> link;

    internal Node<T> Link
    {
        get { return link; }
        set { link = value; }
    }

    public Node<T>(T p)
    {
        data = p; 
    }
}
```

Then you could use this in your code like this, by creating a LinkedList< Item > ... a LinkedList of 'Item' objects.

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList<Item> Books = new LinkedList<Item>();
            Item book1 = new Item(101, "Avatar: Legend of Korra", 13.50);
            Item book2 = new Item(102, "Avatar: Legend of Aang", 10.60);
            Books.AddFront(book1);
            Books.AddFront(book2);

            Books.DisplayAll();
        }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that, with very minor changes to your original code, your LinkedList can now hold ANY type of object - but remains strongly typed. It also decouples your LinkedList and Node implementation from your BookApp code.

Answer (score 0):

For your compiler error: you're trying to assing an `Item` to an `int`, which won't work.

You can replace the `private int data [...] public int Data` part and the constructor with the following:

```
public Item Data { get; set; }

public Node(BookApp.Item item)
{
    Data = item;
}
```

As for why `DisplayAll()` returns `0`, you have to debug the issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal you get that error, the variable p is type of Item. You cannot implicity convert type Item to int. Your Data variable must be an Item variable.